# Syntax error: expecting rightparen before not

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm required to use ActionScript 3.0 in Adobe Animate for my latest project. It is really difficult for me to understand because I'm still. If any of you guys can help me solve this problem I am truly grateful to you.

here's where Adobe Animate said my coding is wrong

```
if (left && up !right && !down) {
    mc_car.rotation = 315;
}
if (right && up !left && !down) {
    mc_car.rotation = 45;
}
if (left && up !right && !up) {
    mc_car.rotation = 225;
}
if (right && up !left && !up) {
    mc_car.rotation = 135;
}
```

1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before not

Comment: Can you explain what this line is supposed to be doing `if (left && up !right && !down)`?

Comment: Each of your `if`-clauses has a syntax error. `if (left && up [and/or missing here] !right && !down) {`.  What's it supposed to do? It should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the && between your two conditions in each if statement. And brackets grouping each condition's components.

Here's how your code should look.

```
if ((left && up) && (!right && !down)) {
    mc_car.rotation = 315;
}
if ((right && up) && (!left && !down)) {
    mc_car.rotation = 45;
}
if ((left && up) && (!right && !up)) {
    mc_car.rotation = 225;
}
if ((right && up) && (!left && !up)) {
    mc_car.rotation = 135;
}
```

Comment: The brackets should be standard, not optional. the compiler treats everything in a bracket as **one result**. If they put `(left && up && !right && !up)` it looks bad to the compiler, how can one result have an expectation of `&& up` but also have `&& !up` in same condition setup? I suspect some of these are supposed to be **Or** using (`||`) but the Asker does not respond to clarification queries, so no-one can help them further

Comment: You're spot on.